# Why am I Getting this error" foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '' because '' not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' "

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am getting this error in my razor view

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Kitap' because 'Kitap' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator' ilk C:\Users\90537\source\repos\ilk\ilk\Views\Home\Index5.cshtml    17  Active

Here is the controller method:

```
 public IActionResult Index5()
        {
            var ktp = new List<Kitap>() {
                new Kitap(){Id=1,KitapAd="alem",Yazar="verne"},
                new Kitap(){Id=2,KitapAd="mektup",Yazar="zwayg"},
                new Kitap(){Id=3,KitapAd="noel" ,Yazar="ben"}

            };
            return View(ktp);
        }
```

And Here is the rest of my code

```
  @model ilk.Models.Kitap

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index5</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        @foreach (var ks in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>ks.</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </table>
```

Comment: You declared your model to be a Kitap, not a List of Kitap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your code in the View page as below:

```
  @model List<ilk.Models.Kitap>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index5</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        @foreach (var ks in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>ks.</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </table>
```